# Exchnging fname and lname through javascript

Tags: javascript

How to exchange first name with last name in javascript? For ex: If i am entering 'abc xyz' in an input box, how to get the output as 'xyz abc'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your string using `split()`, store the values in respective variables and use like whatever you want:

```js
let fullName = 'abc xyz';
let [fname, lname] = fullName.split(" ");

console.log(`${lname} ${fname}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the name string, [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array, and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the reversed array back into a string.

```js
var name = 'firstname lastname';

console.log(name.split(' ').reverse().join(' '));
```